# Implementar Función para Insertar desde OracleDB en Node.JS

Tags: nodejs, oracle, express, post

Busco orientación al tema correcto para investigar y aplicar la solución correcta. Tengo una función X en OracleBD, la cual inserta un registro con parámetros dentro de una tabla. Usamos estas mismas funciones en desarrollos en Java, en los cuales, las utilizamos sin problema. ¿Qué cambió? Tratamos de implementar una plantilla nueva con base en NodeJS, pero no he encontrado información que me ayude a descifrar como ejecutar la función. Usamos Express en nodejs asi como oracleDB.Cabe mencionar que en nuestra plantilla original en Java, usamos Map<String, Object> para pasarle los parametros a la BD y recibirlos desde BD. Cualquier ayuda o enlace a la documentación correcta agredeceria mucho.

Esta sería el rout del HTTP post del problema:

```
// Registro de dataTableVehiculo
this.router.post(`${this.path}/registro/vehiculos/informe`, this.repuveController.postDataTableVehiculos);
```

Este sería el controlador:

```
// Endpoint para registrar dataTable
public postDataTableVehiculos = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const paramsDataTable = req?.body; //son 20 parametros dentro del body
};
```

La función en BD:

```
create or replace function FNALTAREPUVE
(PARAMS...)
RETURN XXXX.patypes.rcgcursor
```

Comment: Veo que la función de nodejs que compartes (`postDataTableVehiculos`) no hace nada, lo que estás preguntando es como implementar esta función en express para guardar la información que recibes en el body usando la función de Oracle? o ya tienes una implementación en nodejs pero no la compartiste aquí?

Comment: Justamente, busco como implementar la función en express. Busqué un par de ejemplos en stack de funciones o stored Proc, pero no consigo impactar la base de datos. Realmente soy nuevo en node.

Comment: Ok entiendo, no se si has visto esto pero la [documentación de Express](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/database-integration.html#oracle) tiene una sección donde hablan sobre como conectarse a una base de datos Oracle usando un módulo llamado [oracledb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb). En teoría con esto tendrías que crear la conexión a tu base de datos pasando la configuración y el connection string y posteriormente ejecutar la función sql que quieres llamar usando esa conexión.

Comment: La conexión ya la implementé. Solo no encuentro pies ni cabeza a como llamar las funciones. Pero sigo leyendo documentación de oracle y node para ver si encuentro algo que hile todo junto. Gracias.